# Opening .txt files with my custom notepad error

Tags: c#, editor, notepad

For the past few days I've been developing a custom notepad. I've created a lot of buttons etc, with one of them being "Open File" which is used to open `.txt` files.

It works smoothly, however, if I were to open a `.txt` file by clicking on it, and not opening it from the app itself, the `.txt` file appears blank.

The next few print screens can as well describe the situation better :

1) [image]
2) [image]
3) [image]
4) [image]

The code I tried last time was this  :

```
// Path being path = ofd.FileName; 
   ofd = OpenFileDialog


   if (File.Exists(path))
      {
       sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
       userTB.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
       this.Name = path;
       sr.Close();
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open the file with your associated program. You'll have to check the arguments send to your program.

In your program.cs you can retrieve these arguments.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //with args(user open file with the program)
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            string fileName = args[0];
            //Check file exists
            if(File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                //start your application with the path argument and use it to open the file onload
            }

        }
            //without args
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Comment: [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/809638/Open-associated-files-with-Csharp-program) could also help you:

Comment: I either get a message telling me that "                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);  needs to be compiled before WIN32 starts smth" or if i change the code to something like http://prntscr.com/9vm7jf  then the program doesnt even open.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. But what you can do, is open your form with an argument. Application.Run(new Form1(fileName)); But this will require you to change your form constructor. Since you like sending screenshots, here is a screenshot how your constructor should look like: [link](http://puu.sh/mLSh0/b5d832625a.png).
The first constructor will be called when there is no argument present, otherwise the other one will execute.